# Why SAP select-option error when put "i" for SIGN values?

Tags: java, parameters, digital-signature, abap, jco

I want to ask about SAP software. So, I want to request data from SAP system in certain server (not mine, and I can't open the server), and the server admin gave me SELECT-OPTION values, so I can use these parameter to request. But, he gave me "i" character for sign parameter values. And with "i" (lowercase), my query from JAVA became error, and it shows me message

> Incorrect 'SIGN' in SELECT-OPTIONS or RANGES table

So I want to ask, is SIGN values have to be in upper case? or lower case also can. If lower case also can, why I got that error?

Thanks all...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an upper-case `I`.

Comment: so its the standart for SIGN property field, right? but the SAP administrator said that he can use "i" in lower case, but when I call it from JAVA, its result an error...

Comment: see my comment to the other answer

Answer (score -1):

ABAP is not case sensitive but JAVA is.
If you are calling it from ABAP it will work with i or I.
If you are calling it from JAVA you need to use it as described in the API(uppercase).

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Of course ABAP is case-sensitive, but the UI layer has a built-in conversion for fields that are flagged as "upper-case only".

Comment: @vwegert Do me a favor before downvoting my comment.
Create a batch-input.
Now look at the start-of-selection. You will note is lowercase like the one in this link: http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/trigger-output-redetermination-for-billing-documents-using-batch-input.aspx
Now create your report and write start-of-selection. The IDE will convert that to uppercase.
Both work. start-of-selection and START-OF-SELECTION.
That's the definition of case-insensitive.

Comment: The definition of "batch input" is "going through the UI layer" - it's not the IDE that does the conversion.